# LoadBalancing JDBC DataSource Connect without URL

Tags: oracle, jdbc, load-balancing

When using JDBC I like the new `DataSource-way` to establish the connection. Further I like the isolated set-Methods for the properties like `setUser`, `setPassword`, `setDriverType`, `setServerName`, `setNetworkProtocol`, `setDatabaseName`, `setPortNumber` and so on.
The question is (esp. for the use with Oracle), if there is a way to set up LoadBalancing with two or more servers without specifying the URL directly with

```
setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(LOAD_BALANCE=ON)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=dbsrv1)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=dbsrv2)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=dbpool)))");
```

for example.

Comment: Maybe someone could add the tags `datasource`, `load-balancing` and `connection`? Thanks.

Comment: It's easier to do it using `tnsnames.ora`, but that doesn't answer your question ;)

Answer (score 2):

Thin client can also use alias defined in tnsnames.ora. In java call set -Doracle.net.tns_admin=... 
 http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/urls.htm